# Make good use of CPUs within one function or run it parallel?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, cpu

Here is the problem. I have thousands of formulas to evaluate and access, such as 'rank(sqrt(v1))' or 'corr(v1, square(v2))'. All values(v1, v2, ...) have been shared on memory for multiprocessing. I have one function and all computations within it just use numpy or scipy functions.

```py
from scipy.stats import rankdata
import multiprocessing as np

def myeval(formula):
   ... # read from shared_memory
   ... # compute 
   return value

def eval_access(formula):
   factor = myeval(formula)  # comsumes 1GB memory 
   factor_performance1 = rankdata(factor, axis=1)  # another Gigabyte
   factor_performance2 = np.full_like(factor, np.nan)  # another one
   ...  # some computation
   pickle_part  # some I/O to record performance (just some float number)
   return 

with mp.Pool(30) as p:
   p.map(eval_access, all_formulas)
```

Running this function on parallel can make good use of all CPUs(almost 100% usage every second), but each process will consume at most 3GB, so 30 processes may consume at most 60GB memory simutaneously. And also, it seems numpy operations under multiprocessing will slow down. To avoid these problems, I want to use all CPUs within eval_access function as follows.

```py
from scipy.stats import rankdata
import multiprocessing as np


def myeval(ind1, ind2):
   # alter value[ind1:ind2, :] or value[:, ind1:ind2]

def myeval_multiprocess(formula):
   # read from shared_memory
   value = np.zeros(shape)  # prepare return value's space
   ... # share_memory value
   
   ...# split value's index into 30 parts
   with mp.Pool(30) as p:
      p.map(myeval, ind_list)

   return value

def eval_access(formula):
   factor = myeval_multiprocess(formula)  # comsumes 1GB memory 
   factor_performance1 = rankdata(factor, axis=1)  # another Gigabyte
   factor_performance2 = np.full_like(factor, np.nan)  # another one
   ...  # some computation
   pickle_part  # some I/O to record performance (just some float number)
   return 

for formula in all_formulas:
   eval_access(formula)
```

This is an ideal situation where these two versions will cost the same time and the latter one needs less memory anytime. However, the problem is it costs a lot of time to share_memory value within myeval_multiprocess and not all methods in eval_access can make good use of all CPUs, unless I decorate all functions I will use to support split the whole problem into some subsets.

So, are there any suggestions on which version is better or how to speed up, and can the latter one run ideally? Meanwhile, is there any method that can multiprocessing every computation easily?

Comment: Do you have more than 60GB RAM? If not, just reduce the multiprocessing pool size to something that's more manageable

Comment: @Stuart Nope, so I can only run the old function on parallel with at most 15 cores. But the parallelled function, I can use all 36 cores. I wonder should I keep parallelling every sub-method in that function?

Comment: You have to strike a balance between available CPUs and RAM. If you overload all cores at the expensive of having to work with virtual memory (swapping) then then it's not going to perform well. Also, with large numbers of processes accessing shared memory, there's going to be a lot of time spent in contention (locks, semaphores etc). This is likely to be a classic case of "less is more" and for you that probably means fewer concurrent processes. Also, lucky you for having a 36-core CPU